# \pageref to customised float environment

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing

I would like to include some pictures in my document that are not really figures and should therefore not appear in the list-of-figures. They are to cover a whole page each, which I achieved using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage
\begin{textblock*}{\textheight}(20mm,34mm)
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{landscape.png}}]{landscape.png}}
\end{textblock*}
\label{pic:ref}
~\newpage

\lipsum[3]
\pageref{pic:ref}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

`textpos` is obviously not the way to go here, as it is not floating, resulting in ugly typesetting of the page prior to the picture. Further does this not set an anchor, such that `\pageref` doesn't work either.

**How do I define a new type of float that also allows for anchoring without having a caption?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just create my own float using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,float}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{myfloatcntr}
\newfloat{myfloat}{p}{myf}[chapter]
\newcommand{\labelmyfloat}{%
  \refstepcounter{myfloatcntr}\label}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{myfloat}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=.8\textheight]{example-image-a}
\labelmyfloat{pic:ref}
\end{myfloat}

\lipsum[3]
\pageref{pic:ref}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The above provides `myfloat`. You can use `\labelmyfloat` as new "labelling mechanism". It merely steps the unused counter `myfloatcntr` in order to set the reference for the float.

Comment: To this end, you technically don't need a new float type (you can still use `figure`). It's just better to create something that is named according to its usage, so you have better control over how it is handled.